# Who came up with the idea of displaying *ZOK*, *POW* etc as words in a fight?

Tags: analysis, batman-1966

If you do not know the Batman fights, here is an example:

The effect (at least for me) is ludicrous, I cannot take the fights seriously and it does not matter anymore who wins. It not only breaks the suspension of disbelief, it shreds it.

**Who invented the word fights?**

**Was it deliberately presented because:**

- it is straight out copied from the comic book
- it intends to mollify violence by ridiculing it
- it was an intended comedic effect?

**Had it the same effect on the 1960 viewers like me?**

Comment: You do realise the whole tv show wasn't meant to be taken seriously? It's **intended* to be campy - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman_(TV_series)

Comment: @Paulie_D Yeah, the Antishark-Batspray and the gigantic needle deathtrap was a straight pointer. But I still wondered because the use of words is really unique (AFAIK), I never saw it in other comedies or superhero movies.

Comment: I'm trying to find a sourced reference but so far I've just found [These fight scene graphics served a dual purpose. They helped tie Batman back to its comic book origins while covering up the terribly choreographed fight scenes (most punches never landed on the body of the intended victims).](http://www.methodshop.com/2006/05/batman-fight-graphics.shtml)

Comment: No, no, you've missed the point. The show was developed as a _situation comedy_, and humorous visual effects made the fight scenes _comic_, by turning them into something akin to _Tom and Jerry_, in which the most outrageous things happen but no one actually gets hurt. It made the live-action show the closest thing to a _cartoon_ on the air. William Dozier, the show's executive producer, famously described the show as the only sitcom on the network that didn't have a laugh-track. You need to read the book, _Back to the Batcave_, about the making of the show, to see why they made it as comedy.

Answer (score 4):

These are called [onomatopoeias](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/onomatopoeia). Every language on the planet recognizes them. The very first human speech was [composed heavily of them](http://www.evoanth.net/2015/10/29/onomatopoeia-the-origin-of-language/).

As noted by [Paulie_D](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/34317/paulie-d) in the [comments](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/78077/who-came-up-with-the-idea-of-displaying-zok-pow-etc-as-words-in-a-fight/78083#comment128416_78077), they [originated in the print comic](http://www.methodshop.com/2006/05/batman-fight-graphics.shtml) version of the cartoon.

Taking a step deeper, culture historian Tim DeForest credits cartoonist [Roy Crane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roy_Crane) for being the [first to use them in comics](https://books.google.com/books?id=1xAXWwYchscC&pg=PA116):

> It was Crane who pioneered the use of onomatopoeic sound effects in
>   comics, adding "**bam**," "**pow**" and "**wham**" to what had previously been an
>   almost entirely visual vocabulary. Crane had fun with this, tossing in
>   an occasional "ker-splash" or "lickety-wop" along with what would
>   become the more standard effects. Words as well as images became
>   vehicles for carrying along his increasingly fast-paced storylines.

Onomatopoeias have a certain [psychological effect](https://mindmodeling.org/cogsci2014/papers/496/paper496.pdf). For this reason they are also used heavily in advertising (think snap, crackle, pop). They are good way to express a sound or feeling in text. They sound cheesy to a modern person because they're not used in video anymore, but back before modern sound effects became ubiquitous these psychological effects were much more prominent. Today every modern action movie uses equally cheesy and unrealistic sound effects instead of Onomatopoeias, but most modern moviegoers don't even notice them. Perhaps in the future someone will ask *why do all these old movies have super cheesy sound effects?*

Answer (score -1):

**Batman** was a comedy - famously, it was described as *the only situation comedy on the air without a laugh-track*.

These visual effects were intended to be *funny*.